# jq command to filter keys based on value being > a number?

Tags: json, key, jq

I have a simple JSON blob as below:

```
{
  "thing_one": 223,
  "thing_two": 0,
  "thing_three": 0,
  "thing_four": 69,
  "thing_five": 14,
  "thing_six": 0
}
```

I want to select the keys whose value is > 10. I want the output of my `jq` command to return a list containing just the keys that meet this criterion. In the above example, it would return `"thing_one, thing_four, thing_five"`. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
jq 'to_entries[] | select(.value > 10) | .key'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to_entries[] | select( .value>10 ) | .key
```

produces a stream of keys:

```
"thing_one"
"thing_four"
"thing_five"
```

Use the -r command-line option to remove the quotation marks.

To widen your horizons, consider these alternatives:

```
keys[] as $key
| if .[$key] > 10 then $key else empty end
```

Using `foreach`:

```
foreach keys[] as $key (.; .; if .[$key] > 10 then $key else empty end)
```

As for the best, I think you'll find that the second alternative above is the most succinct of the best performing possibilities in jq.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **delpaths** and **paths** to remove values <= 10

```
delpaths([paths(. <= 10)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [jq170727's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45517701/112968), you can stream the paths, without having to invert the condition and delete everything else:

```
paths(.>10)[]
```

Output:

```
"thing_one"
"thing_four"
"thing_five"
```

To get the *exact* output from your question, join the values:

```
[paths(.>10)[]] | join(", ")
```

Output:

```
"thing_one, thing_four, thing_five"
```